# setting crontab from bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, cron

I have written the following script but i am getting error `sqlcorn.sh: No such file or directory`

here is the script

```
#!/bin/bash
ORACLE_HOME="/opt/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1"
ORACLE_SID="HEER"
ORACLE_USER="USER1"
ORACLE_PASSWORD="USERP"

echo "export ORACLE_HOME=$ORACLE_HOME" >> sqlcronprocedure.sh
echo "export PATH=\$ORACLE_HOME/bin:\$PATH" >> sqlcronprocedure.sh
echo "export ORACLE_SID=$ORACLE_SID" >> sqlcronprocedure.sh
echo "rTmpDir=/tmp" >> sqlcronprocedure.sh

echo "sqlplus -s $ORACLE_USER@$ORACLE_SID/$ORACLE_PASSWORD  > $rTmpDir/deleteme.txt 2>&1 <<EOF" >> sqlcronprocedure.sh
echo "    select 1 from dual;" >> sqlcronprocedure.sh
echo "    execute someproc(1000,14);" >> sqlcronprocedure.sh
echo "EOF" >> sqlcronprocedure.sh

chmod 755 sqlcronprocedure.sh

crontab -l > sqlcron.sh
echo "0,15,30,45 * * * * /sqlcronprocedure.sh" >> sqlcron.sh
crontab sqlcorn.sh
```

This is my first ever script. so i apologize if things are too obvious to ask

Comment: Nice job for your first script -- except for the typo (see my answer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The real problem: You misspelled the file name on the `crontab` command.  Change it from:

```
crontab sqlcorn.sh
```

to

```
crontab sqlcron.sh
```

Some more comments on your code:

Your multiple `echo` commands are better written as a "here document".  Rather than this:

```
echo "export ORACLE_HOME=$ORACLE_HOME" >> sqlcronprocedure.sh
echo "export PATH=\$ORACLE_HOME/bin:\$PATH" >> sqlcronprocedure.sh
echo "export ORACLE_SID=$ORACLE_SID" >> sqlcronprocedure.sh
echo "rTmpDir=/tmp" >> sqlcronprocedure.sh

echo "sqlplus -s $ORACLE_USER@$ORACLE_SID/$ORACLE_PASSWORD  > $rTmpDir/deleteme.txt 2>&1 <<EOF" >> sqlcronprocedure.sh
echo "    select 1 from dual;" >> sqlcronprocedure.sh
echo "    execute someproc(1000,14);" >> sqlcronprocedure.sh
echo "EOF" >> sqlcronprocedure.sh
```

you can do this:

```
cat <<EOF >sqlcronprocedure.sh
export ORACLE_HOME=$ORACLE_HOME
export PATH=\$ORACLE_HOME/bin:\$PATH
export ORACLE_SID=$ORACLE_SID
rTmpDir=/tmp
EOF

cat <<END_OF_SCRIPT >sqlcronprocedure.sh
export ORACLE_HOME=$ORACLE_HOME
export PATH=\$ORACLE_HOME/bin:\$PATH
export ORACLE_SID=$ORACLE_SID
rTmpDir=/tmp

sqlplus -s $ORACLE_USER@$ORACLE_SID/$ORACLE_PASSWORD  > $rTmpDir/deleteme.txt 2>&1 <<EOF
    select 1 from dual;
    execute someproc(1000,14);
EOF
END_OF_SCRIPT
```

which is a bit easier to read.  (Your version wasn't incorrect, just hard to read and error-prone; you have to get the `>> sqlcronprocedure.sh` right on eacn and every line.)

Note: You use `>>` to build `sqlcronprocedure.sh`, which appends to the existing `sqlcronprocedure.sh` if it exists.  I don't *think* that's what you want to do; you probably want to create the file from scratch.  My code assumes you want to create the file rather than appending to it.

The last part of your script:

```
crontab -l > sqlcron.sh
echo "0,15,30,45 * * * * /sqlcronprocedure.sh" >> sqlcron.sh
crontab sqlcorn.sh
```

is fine except for two things.

First `sqlcron.sh` is not a good name for the file, since it's not a shell script; just call it `sqlcron`.  The system doesn't care, but you should.

Second, the misspelling I mentioned above.

Answer (score -1):

you need to specify the full path to sqlcron.sh in your script...

Comment: I have modified my script and has added this command when writing to file `${PWD##*/}filename` but i am still getting error `sqlcron.sh: No Such file or Directory`

Comment: No, you don't.  `sqlcron.sh` isn't a shell script; it's just given as an argument to `crontab`.  And `${PWD##*/}` doesn't refer to the current directory anyway; `${PWD}` does.  @EmAe: Why did you accept this answer?

Comment: he made me realize what the msitake was .. I was referring to a `sqlcorn` at one place .. i should have referred to `sqlcron` :)